# Mono return error: mono mscorlib.dll was not found

Tags: .net, mono, gtk, monodevelop, mscorlib

I've developed a mono gtk 2.10 application with monodevelop 2.4.

But, when i try to launch the .exe outside my develop machine (about 5 virtual machine) i get ever:

> mono mscorlib.dll was not found

Also if i add mscorlib.dll to the app directory, i get the same error.

Where i'm wrong ?

Comment: If unsolved please update your question with the operating system (and version) where you have this problem.

Comment: Need a little more to go on, what runtime are you aiming your app at? 1.1, 2.0, 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *might* be that your program was built against a version of the runtime that isn't installed on the other machines.

For instance, If you compiled against 1.1 or 4.0 and your other systems only have 2.0 or 3.5 etc.

Given that you are having these kinds of problems, you might want to look at [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Bundles). If you do not need to distribute your program to third parties you might want to use the `--static` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
% MONO_PATH=. mono yourapp.exe
```

It will make mono look in the current directory to find its files. But if your environment is not set correctly you'll likely have other issues (e.g. finding the GAC, machine.config...). Look at the mono-project.com wiki for more information.