# How can I fix a missing mscorelib.dll error that occurs when trying to run a Mono for Android app?

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, mscorlib

In MonoDevelop when compiling and running an app developed for Android against the simulator, the app compiles then crashes immediately in the simulator with the following application output...

```
E/mono    (  225): The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
E/mono    (  225): It should have been installed in the `/home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/BUILD/armeabi/install/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll' directory.
```

Keep in mind that I'm not Jon so I don't even know where it's getting the /home/jon path configuration. Though I have found that path in other similar but ultimately unrelated searches on the internet so I imagine it's a path on some other devs machine.

mscorlib.dll is indeed on my machine. located here...

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/

and here...

/Developer/MonoAndroid/usr/lib/mono/2.1/

I've tried targetting various Android SDK environments (currently 2.3 and the simulator is currently running under the 2.3 SDK environment as well).

I'm on Mac OSx 10.7.2. Using the latest version of MonoDevelop, Mono and Mono for Android. I've also got the latest MonoTouch installed as well and iPhone apps compile fine if that's worth anything.

The closest thing I can find to a hint at the issue is here...
http://phonicuk.com/Forums/ViewThread.aspx?tid=401

I've tried reinstalling Mono and Mono for Android but admittedly have not tried uninstalling in entirely before a reinstall. I've searched within files for the /home/jon path thinking that it must be a configuration somewhere but haven't been able to find it anywhere.

I found this... [Mono return error: mono mscorlib.dll was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855684/mono-return-error-mono-mscorlib-dll-was-not-found)

Along with a few other things that were sort of in the same vein, but ultimately nothing that seems to be a fix.

Any ideas?

**Update**: From the suggestions in jonp's answer below it indeed seems like the Mono.Android.DebugRuntime package is not installed. So far I've tried a couple of MonoAndroid reinstalls and have tried removing MonoAndroid entirely beforehand. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to add the package manually, but I'm so new to this.

**Another update**: Not sure why I didn't try this already, but I created a HelloWorld MonoAndroid app and it works fine. The compilation took a while longer too for that one and I could see if was setting up the required packages, so there has to be an issue with the specific solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you install a Debug build of your app on the device, three `.apk` files are installed:

1. `Mono.Android.DebugRuntime`, which contains `libmonosgen-2.0.so`, `mscorlib.dll`, etc.
2. `Mono.Android.Plaltform.ApiLevel_N`, which contains `Mono.Android.dll` for API level `N`.
3. Your application.

My guess is that the `Mono.Android.DebugRuntime` package has not been installed. To check this, run:

```
adb shell pm list packages | grep Mono.Android
```

I'm going to guess that it's missing. :-)

Next, why is it missing? When you Run the app within MonoDevelop, all required packages are checked for and installed. It seems rather odd that it wouldn't be. Is your device low on disk space?

```
adb shell df /data
```

How are you launching the emulator? If you're launching within MonoDevelop, there should be enough free space to install all of the above packages. However, if you launch it yourself, the default `/data` size is 64MB, which isn't enough to support a Debug build environment. Please launch the simulator from MonoDevelop and re-Run your app, or [launch the emulator so that it has enough free space](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/troubleshooting#There_is_not_enough_storage_space_on_the_device_to_deploy_the_package):

```
emulator -partition-size 512 -avd YOUR_AVD_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're correct that Mono.Android is missing. Weird. I'm not low on disk space (it's at 496 and only 34 is being used) and I'm launching the emulator from within monodevelop. I basically followed this Xamarin Anroid tutorial when setting up the environment... http://android.xamarin.com/Installation_for_Mac. I also just realized, I bet you're the Jon aren't you?